# How to declare session variable as global in Golang

Tags: session, go, global-variables

I do not want to repeat this code every time I want to create a session :

```
 var shash, _ = bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(os.Getenv("SESSION_KEY")), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
var store = sessions.NewCookieStore(shash)
session, serr := store.Get(r, "session-name")
if serr != nil {
    ....
}
```

So, I created a function in a file `inc/inc.go` in package `inc` :

```
func initSession(r *http.Request){
    var shash, _ = bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(os.Getenv("SESSION_KEY")), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    var store = sessions.NewCookieStore(shash)
    session, serr := store.Get(r, "session-name")
    if serr != nil {
        log.Fatal(serr)
        return
    }
}
```

The function `initSession` initializes the session object.

There are also global variables in the file `inc.go`, example :

```
var DbName string = "dbname"
var DbUser string = "user"
var DbPass string = "pass"
var DbHost string ="localhost"
```

So that I can access these variables from any file that imports package `inc`.

My problem is that I do not know how to make `session` in the function initSession global like the other variables? so that I can access it using `inc.Session` ?

Also, how do I declare the variable with `var Session type` , given that I am using package `github.com/gorilla/sessions`, what should I replace `type` with?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to inject these parameters into the objects/function who need it instead of trying to create something "global" or "static"?

Comment: you mean, return session, and call InitSession everytime I want it? ... the problem is that I want to call InitSession only once (in the main function)

Comment: Use `var Session *sessions.Session` at the package level, then at the bottom of your `initSession` do `Session = session`.

Comment: Thank you so much mkopriva , I will check it out, meanwhile, add your comment as an answer to the question. Best

Comment: it worked ! thank you so much, that's what I was looking for `*sessions.Session` , thanks again .. please add it as an answer so that I can accept it as a best answer.